# Little issue with canvas

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run this code, where the constructor is the ball function, and the `ball.prototype.draw` is the prototype which should include the code in ball.

Can't seem to display the drawing of the ball.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('ok');
var d = canvas.getContext('2d');
function Ball() {
  ok = 100;
  okk = 100;
};

var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle){
  d.beginPath();
  d.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if(fillCircle){
    d.fill();
  } else{
    d.stroke(); } };  

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  d.lineWidth = 2;
  d.strokeStyle = "black";
  d.fillStyle = "red";
  circle(ok, okk, 30, true); };

Ball.prototype.draw();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Your title should be a short version of your question, not a request for help. You need to include a clear description of what the code is meant to do and what **specific** problem you're having with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the prototypes in JS, you still would need to instantiate a new instance of the object you're modeling.

So your code is fine, except the last line; instead you want to create a new ball and then call the member function `draw` on it, like so:

```
//Ball.prototype.draw();
var ball = new Ball();
ball.draw();
```